# Focus() not working in Firebug Console

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I am trying to use Mozilla Firefox Firebug Console to test some code.  Below is the line I am trying to execute to focus on the link:

```
document.getElementById('DEPT_TBL_DESCR$prompt').focus();
```

But it keeps returning this error in Firebug Console:

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Does anyone know why or how I could focus on that link/img?

Below is the code:

```
<a href="javascript:pAction_win0(document.win0,'DEPT_TBL_DESCR$prompt');" tabindex="35" id="DEPT_TBL_DESCR$prompt" name="DEPT_TBL_DESCR$prompt"><img border="0" align="absmiddle" title="Look up New Department ID (Alt+5)" alt="Look up New Department ID (Alt+5)" src="/cs/hr34/cache/PT_PROMPT_LOOKUP_1.gif"></a>
```

This is related to this IE error message:
Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus.

Comment: Is your id is correct if yes then change your id and try by removing $ symbol

Comment: I removed it and it still didn't work..

Comment: Can you post it on jsfiddle so that i can help

Comment: I can't post it, but I added this line in Console and the alert said 'null'.      alert(document.getElementById('DEPT_TBL_DESCRprompt'));

Comment: i cant guess then because its working in my firefox

Comment: Where are you executing that line?  If you are executing it before the DOM has been rendered, then that element won't be available yet.

Answer (score 0):

"$" is not a valid character as part of an ID or name for an HTML 4 element.

See: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Though it is allowed on HTML5: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute.

You have not sated which you are using.

Comment: I took out the $ and it still didn't work.  That is not the issue.